# Deploy Storybook on Netlify with Nextjs

Tags: next.js, netlify, storybook

I am trying to deploy my Storybook on Netlify, I'm using **Next.js** framework but it fails every time and I don't know what is wrong

Netlify configuration :

Build command: `npm run build-storybook`

Publish directory: `storybook-static`

My package.json:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://github.com/alexCoding42/tailwind-storybook",
  "name": "tailwind-storybook",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "10.0.9",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@netlify/plugin-nextjs": "^3.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.2.0-alpha.22",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.2.0-alpha.22",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.2.0-alpha.22",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.2.0-alpha.22",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.35",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  }
}
```

The error I get on Netlify:

```
Plugin "@netlify/plugin-nextjs" internal error

Error: No static assets found in .next dist (aka no /.next/static). Please check your project configuration. Your next.config.js must be one of serverless or experimental-serverless-trace. Your build command should include next build.
```

I have also tried to add a `netlify.toml` at the root of my project with this config:

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build-storybook"
  publish = "storybook-static"

[[plugins]]
  package = "@netlify/plugin-nextjs"
```

And added `@netlify/plugin-nextjs`as dev dependency of package.json but I get the same error...

Can someone help me on this please ?

Comment: I think the plugin used is intended to load nextjs project and since the storybook is not a nextjs app, the plugin looks for /.next/static folder to deploy. I think that the plugin should be changed

Comment: did you fix this somehow?

Comment: I wasn't able to fix it. As a solution alternative I used Chromatic and deploy my Storybook on it https://www.chromatic.com/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but not with the storybook but with nx + nextjs.

If I tried to deploy the app to the netlify I got the same error.

[image]

So I changed next.config.js in the root directory and add to [distDir](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/setting-a-custom-build-directory) path to generated .static folder and it's working now.

[image]

[image]

and this is my netlify.toml ss

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Netlify Next.js plugin isn't required for a Storybook build. In fact, no plugins are required; the only configuration needed is, as OP says:

- Build command: `npm run build-storybook`
- Publish directory: `storybook-static`

Or, in `netlify.toml`:

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build-storybook"
  publish = "storybook-static"
```

No `[[plugins]]` fields are needed.

If Netlify is configured through the UI, go to https://app.netlify.com/sites/my-awesome-site/plugins and remove the Next.JS plugin.